# Node reference field autocomplete and allow multiple selections in views

Tags: 8, views

I recently pdated my Drupal core to 8.9 and suddenly a functionality stops working.

I have a "Recipe" content type, it has a field of "Category" (field_category) which is Entity Reference: Node.

I tried to create a View and created a filter criteria field_category, and I want it to be Auto complete and Allow multiple selections.

I know its possible on Entity Reference Taxonomy, but currently its not possible on Entity Reference Node.

I found Views Autocomplete Filters (https://www.drupal.org/project/views_autocomplete_filters), but I want it to Allow multiple selections.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do this in Drupal 7 (yes, I've told the site owner they need to upgrade, but here I am). I can't believe that I've been working on Drupal sites over a decade, and never realized that I can't "Allow multiple selections" on entity reference fields in views. It seems like such a basic thing.

Comment: Follow up, this can be done with a contextual filter, use the "Raw value from URL", then you can add the ids as /1234+5678 etc., and to include all results, just use /all. This is fine for me since I am building an API, but it might not work if you need it as an exposed filter, but it gets the job done at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem using this module:

https://gist.github.com/StryKaizer/ae1cb9abc4844a9e7ac12317a9d84a78